# Choosing a computer for blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, armature, game-engine, system

which is a better starter computer for blender
1.HP Folio 9480m 
2.HP EliteBook 840 G3

Comment: This kind of question won't be answered here.

Comment: So, where can I get it answered?

Comment: I don't know. Try to google it. Questions about hardware recommandations are out of topic in BSE.